# How do I get the storyline missions to start?

Tags: uplink

According to [the guide at ModLink](http://guide.modlink.net/section4.php):

> The storyline starts at about April 14th 2010 when the top Uplink Agent (deceased) sends you an email. In this mail will be a link to ARC Central Mainframe, along with his user name and password. In order to enter the storyline, you must connect to ARC Central Mainframe, and try to hack the system using the Codes that the Agent sent you. The codes wont work, but the act of trying alerts ARC to your presence. Before you do this, make sure you have at least 4Gq of memory space left, or you wont get the file that ARC send you when they contact you. A week or two later, ARC will send you an email offering you a job. Accept this and the storyline begins.

When I got the first message, I initially disregarded it.  I left it sitting in my Inbox, and went to take care of the other missions I had queued first.  After I finally got to following up on the message, I logged into the system of interest only to find that it had security systems that were currently beyond my abilities to hack.  So, I left and continued on completing missions until finally I stumbled across a bank account with over 1 million credits.

After acquiring the finances, and buffing my Gateway to the max, I went to follow up on the e-mail.  After the initial failure with the known account credentials, I went through the standard process of hacking the Admin account.  I logged in to the system, expecting to find something interesting on the file server, and found nothing.  I backed out and cleaned up my tracks, and then went in search of a guide.

That's when I found ModLink.  After reading the guide, I hit the fast-forward button to wait for my next message.  However, months have now gone by and I still have nothing.

Is there something I missed, or is my game broken?

Answer (score 3):

First, do missions first because you need heavy software. Fast forward until you see a news that uplink top agent is dead from apparent suicide. After a few days, you will receive an email. It says to stand up against arc. Poke Arc central database for a long time and an email will come. reply the message from arc. I think it's named "an offer you can't refuse".

You will receive a mission and a email with Revelation attached. Arunmor's email will arrive shortly (you must fast forward time). Now choose your side.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do the arc mission didn't get email for two months after poking around so i decided to let then catch me doing it but since I got caught I got a messenger from uplink and got disavowed for trying to hack into arc

Comment: Just to be clear - you experienced the same problem as the asker, but were able to find a solution?

Comment: No he's saying that he tried letting them catch him in the act to trigger the next story action but that failed. He just died.